# Publishing action for Canvas (iframe) apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've provided my canvas app with all required for publishing actions to Facebook. After I publish an action I have a message like "John made an action over {SomeObject}" in my timeline. Everything works OK but the {SomeObject} i click opens in a window, not in facebook iframe where my app usually works. The URL of this link is rendered like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id={my_app_id}&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri={my_object_url}&response_type=code&display=page&auth_referral=1&fb_private_mode_enc={some_text_string}
```

What should i do to make my clicked object open in facebook iframe, not window? Can i somehow change display=page to display=iframe in this URL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem too - I'd like to be able to direct a user straight to my canvas app. Added to this, unless the meta in {my_object_url}'s HTML lines up with what Facebook expects to see, the link resolves to a "this app is having a problem" dialog.

A possible workaround for you, not so much a 100% answer: allow the redirect, but in the meta of the page being redirected to, do an HTML refresh back to the app canvas? This would redirect users back to the app.

If you needed to direct them to a specific page of the app, you could use an app_data [signed request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) addition to the canvas-redirect URL.

Hope this helps. Not a silver bullet though.

PG